# Cannot deploy JavaFX app (Can't build artifact - fx:deploy is not available in this JDK)

Tags: java, jdk, intellij, javafx

I wanted to deploy my first **JavaFX JDK 11** application using IntelliJ. 
I proceeded as follows: 
File -> Project structure -> Artifacts -> MyApp.jar -> OK

Then:

Build -> Build artifacts -> Build
However, I got the following error:
**Error:Java FX Packager: Can't build artifact - fx:deploy is not available in this JDK**

I've read that the last JDK version supporting this way of packing is JDK 10. 
So I switched my project from JDK 11 to JDK 10 but the problem still occurs. 
The app compiles and runs fine in the IDE.

Any suggestions how to solve this?
Thanks :)

Comment: Do you have `openjfx` package installed? JavaFX is not included in the core JDK/JRE any more (since Java 8, I think?) but packaged separately.

Comment: I created a Java project with openJDK 11 and javafx and experienced some of the same problems. I had to add a few arguments when compiling/running for everything to be fine. I'll see what I can dig up

Answer (score 0):

I have worked quite a few hours to fix this. The solution removes all the error messages when trying to run the javafx application as well as trying to execute the jar file outside IntelliJ. 
You need to edit the Manifest file. 
Also to add library + having a proxy (so to  speak) main class executed in order to execute correctly. 
Difficult to explain. But without the last part nothing goes if you have "extends Application" in your Main class. 
Maybe you want to have a look: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D4D7daAmpV4